# Sphinx getting stuck on reading sources index

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

When I input `make html`, Sphinx gets stuck on the reading segment.

By changing a name in of "asp" changes the percentage it gets stuck on. I had it range from 100% to 25%.
Here is an example of what I see in the terminal when I run `make html`:

```
make html
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.2.1
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 2 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [ 50%] asp
```

As said before the 50% is not constant. By changing the name of the asp.rst file it changes the percentage I get. But it has never gone above it.

Here is my asp.rst file:

```
 .. _asp:

 TEST123
 =======


.. automodule:: rcegui
.. module:: RCEController
.. autoclass:: RCE_Control_MainWindow
    :members:
```

Here is my index.rst file:

```
Welcome to GUI's documentation!
===============================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   asp

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Here is the conf.py:

```
import sys
import os
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))

# -- General configuration ------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
'sphinx.ext.doctest',
'sphinx.ext.coverage',
]
```

Removing the coverage extension also changed the reading percentage. But it still got stuck. This seems to be due to the RCEController file, which produces a GUI and needs user inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up checking the --init--.py and it didn't have all the files that the program I was calling needed. So after adding the missing files and restarting it. Sphinx was able to run with no errors. I am not sure what fixed it, but I feel like it was adding the missing files to the --init--.py file.

Comment: Glad to hear it finally worked. Yesterday I really tired and went to sleep. Well, since you mentioned it clearly got something to do with `RCECtronller` module, is it in the same directory as module `recgui`? If yes, then ok. Not yes, then you need `__init__.py` to make it searchable as a python module. I usually don't put  `__init__.py` in my main project, but it is a good practice if you want wrap your whole project as a package.

Comment: @mathmax I had a bunch of different errors when I did not have __init__.py and then this one since it was incomplete. But this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add one line `.. _asp:` at the beginning of `asp.rst`

```
.. _asp:

TEST123
=======

.. automodule:: rcegui
.. module:: RCEController
.. autoclass:: RCE_Control_MainWindow
   :members:
```

for index.rst

```
Welcome to GUI's documentation!
===============================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   asp

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

please follow exact code with correct **indentation** and **space lines**.

For instance, in `rst`, the title and the underline makeup should have the same length.

```
TEST123
=======
```

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov,  see you are using `Sphinx v1.2.1`, maybe try upgrade to the newest `pip install sphinx --upgrade`

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov, If I were you, I will try following: 1) re-generate the `make.bat` and `conf.py`. 2) Since You saw the error has something to do with `asp.rst`, You just put all the contents inside `asp.rst` directly into the `index.rst`. then you check if the problem persist.

Comment: @ mathmax   After moving the contexts of asp.rst to index.rst I got the errors                                                                       /home/nikita/test/doc/index.rst:11: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'.. _asp:'                                                               For each of the lines inside asp.rst

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov, the warning is normal, as it links to `asp.rst` which doesn't exist any more. If you just remove the `tobtree`, then the warning should be gone. So now you can generate the html already. How about you now create `asp.rst` agin with just the the first line `.. _asp:` and a simple header.

Comment: I assume that by 'tobtree' you mean 'toctree'. When I removed it i just got back to my first error. if i dont have any of the modules it reads the file fine

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov, it really strange that after you remove `toctree` the same error came back. And I don't quite understand your ` if i dont have any of the modules it reads the file fine`. Do your mean like `rcegui` in your `asp.rst`. If you remove all the modules, do it works fine? if it does, then we know it must be these modules. If this is the case, how about you try to mock `rcegui` [[1]](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules)?

Comment: if `mock` works fine. I Final thoughts/solution would be you create another sets of mock modules manually without any actual code but just inline `python docstring`. This would be the final workaround and really not elegant.

Comment: Yeah if I remove all the modules in the asp.rst like you have described. What do you mean mock rcegui? I dont think I know how to do that @mathmax

Comment: it cleanly has something to do with the RCEController. I was able to document a program that was simpler and it worked perfectly. is it not able to completely read files that need inputs from the user? If so is there a way around it?